# D3.js Too many text elements leads to performance issues

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm appending over 300 text elements to the center of my polygons. It's fine on my PC but on a mobile device, it begins to stutter, when I start to drag or zoom in my map. Is there any alternative or a different approach?

Here is my code:

```
function setDescription() {
    var arrDescription = ...

        for (var key in arrDescription) {
            var customID = key;
            var strDescription = arrDescription[key];

            svgContainer.selectAll(null)
                .data(feat.features.filter(function(d) {
                    return d.properties.ID == customID;
                }))
                .enter()
                .append("g").attr("id", "txt")
                .attr("transform", function(a) {
                    var centro = path.centroid(a);
                    return "translate(" + centro[0] + "," + centro[1] + ")";
                })
                .append("text")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", function(d) {
                    var bb = path.bounds(d)
                    return ((bb[1][0] - bb[0][0]) / 5) * 0.25 + "px";
                })
                .text(strDescription)
                .attr("pointer-events", "none");
        }
}
```

Comment: Use fewer elements i.e. only ceate what you're going to be able to see.

Comment: So create text elements for polygons within the viewport and remove the rest in real time on panning? Could you provide any example code, please?

Comment: get the parts you need, then load other parts by ajax when you pan.